# How to pass/return subclass attributes from inside another class when creating a new object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, inheritance, subclass

A portion of my code needs a method `def createiPhone(model)` of class `AppleStore` to return one of 3 subclasses `Iphone5S`, `Iphone6`, `Iphone6Plus` and their attributes `make="iPhone", model="5S", price=99.00, height=4.87, width=3.95, weight=2.31, weight_scale="ounces"` when creating a new object `iphone5s = a.createiPhone("iPhone5S")`.

I'm having trouble getting the `def createiPhone(model)` method to select the entered subclass i.e. `iphone5s = a.createiPhone("iPhone5S")`, create the new object `iphone5s` and return its attributes.

**Here is what I have so far for AppleStore Class:**

```
class AppleStore
  def initialize
    @gadgets = []
  end

  def createGadget(make, model, price, height, width, weight, weight_scale)
    gadget = Gadget.new(make, model, price, height, width, weight, weight_scale)
    @gadgets << gadget
    gadget
  end

  def createiPhone(model)
    if model == "iPhone5S"
    gadget = Iphone5S.new(make, model, price, height, width, weight, weight_scale)
    elsif model == "iPhone6"
    gadget = Iphone6.new(make, model, price, height, width, weight, weight_scale)
    else 
    gadget = Iphone6Plus.new(make, model, price, height, width, weight, weight_scale)
    end
    @gadgets << gadget
    gadget
  end
  def revenue_earned
    @gadgets.reduce(0) { |total, gadget| total + gadget.price }
  end

  def products_sold
    @gadgets.count
  end

  def to_s
    "A store having sold #{products_sold} products with revenue of $#{revenue_earned}.00 so far!"
end
end
```

**Here are my 3 subclasses:**

```
class Iphone5S < Gadget
   def initialize(make="iPhone", model="5S", price=99.00, height=4.87, width=3.95, weight=2.31, weight_scale="ounces")
   end
end


class Iphone6 < Gadget
   def initialize(make="iPhone", model="6", price=199.00, height=5.44, width=4.55, weight=2.64, weight_scale="ounces")
   end
end

class Iphone6Plus < Gadget
   def initialize(make="iPhone", model="6Plus", price=299.00, height=6.22, width=6.07, weight=3.06, weight_scale="ounces")
   end
end
```

**Tester:**

```
a = AppleStore.new()
iphone5s = a.createiPhone("iPhone5S")
puts( "here is your iphone5S! " )
puts iphone5s
puts( "here is your AppleStore!" )
puts a
```

**Output:**

```
in `createiPhone': undefined local variable or method `make' 
for A store having sold 2 products with revenue of $648.00 
so far!:AppleStore (NameError)
```

What am I doing wrong here? What is the correct logic for the selection of the subclasses from inside the createiPhone method?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo:
When you define your class, it's called `class Iphone5S`.
But when you initialize it, it starts with a small letter: `gadget = iPhone5S.new`.

Comment: the typo didn't resolve the issue. I appreciate the help but if you check the output I updated, you will see the error.